# When asking a question, deselecting the title input causes a blank page title

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, design

I've noticed that the title at the top now changes as you type in your question's title (I don't remember it doing that before). However, if one doesn't actually type in a title before going onto other parts of the form, it just turns blank, which looks a bit odd:

[image: Blank Title]

I understand why you might want to do this, but I don't really care for it. If you're going to continue using this method, **at least** make it still display the "Ask a Question" part if the title field is still empty.

---

I would personally request that the title **not be changed at all**. It's just annoying, and as a user I honestly wouldn't expect that to happen. If I leave the tab to go do something else, like find a quote or image, and come back to it, I'd **look for "Ask a Question"** in the title, not for what I had typed in as the title. That's just confusing, and it makes the tab look like an actual question which already exists, considering "Ask a Question" is now nowhere to be seen in that title.

**P.S.** How long has the asking page done this? Have I just not noticed it for a while or is it relatively new?

Comment: Actually, it's been around, but I was too lazy to file a big beyond an abandoned post at [meta.ubuntu.se].

Comment: I upvoted because the suggestion "not be changed at all", but I don't care about the empty title issue that much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The next build will start setting the original page title back when the title entry form is cleared.